# Android Studio 3.0. Not show error on Messages windwos

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.0.

Here xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/common_color_bg">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/shoppingDetailsToolBar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingDetailsScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/common_color_bg"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shoppingDetailsToolBar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">   

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/catalog_item_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/shoppingDetailsViewPager"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<!-- here another view items -->

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </FrameLayout>    
    </ScrollView>  

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I has compile error I get this strange message:

[image: first]

Why it's tell me about Kotlin? I have error in xml file!

And only after I open Gradle window I see correct show error:

[image: second]

I want Studio to show me real/correct error message.

Comment: show us ShoppingDetailsAtcivity and its xml

Comment: I update my post

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you call `@BindView(R.id.countInStockTextView)` in the activity `ShoppingDetailsAtcivity` but you don't declare it in your xml : `R.id.countInStockTextView` . Check this id in your xml

Comment: I know what is the problem. The question is: Why Androi Studio show me so strange error message about Kotlin?